# One core data attribute causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1) when leaving app and opening up again

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2, xcode7

I am completely stuck right now:

**Set up**

I have a UISplitViewController. When starting the app, everything loads fine, I can save, delete, edit data no problem. However when I press the home button (`applicationDidEnterBackground`) and go back to the app I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x60)`.
This seems to only happen with one of my attributes.

```
func configureCell(cell: NoteTableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let note = fetchController.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Note

    //deal with NSDate's crap
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle

    //set date and title Label
    cell.dateLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(note.date)
    cell.titleLabel.text = note.title
}
```

The error happens on the `note.date`, when removing it and placing a `NSDate()` instead, there is no error. Notice there is also `note.title` in the code that doesn't crash.
I don't know much about the background of CoreData so I'm not sure where to start.

**Potentially Important Code**

This is the Note NSManagedObject class

```
class Note: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var date: NSDate
@NSManaged var details: String
@NSManaged var title: String
@NSManaged var tag: String
@NSManaged var noteToFolder: NoteData
@NSManaged var noteToData: NSSet

convenience init(date: NSDate, title: String, details: String,tag: String, insertIntoManagedContext context: NSManagedObjectContext){

    let entity: AnyObject = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Note", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
    self.init(entity: entity as! NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

    self.date = date
    self.title = title
    self.details = details
    self.tag = tag


}  


func saveNote(title: String, detail: String,
    predicate: NSPredicate, fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest,
    context: NSManagedObjectContext) {

        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate


        do {
            let fetchResults = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [Note]

            fetchResults!.first?.title = title
            fetchResults!.first?.details = detail
            fetchResults!.first?.date = NSDate()

            try context.save()


        } catch {
            print("Couldn't fetch results")
        }
```

This is in the detail VC, all this VC does is load the Note's title and detail. But even if I don't open this VC, I can reproduce the error.

```
func saveNote() {

    //configure the request
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self == %@", note.objectID)
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Note")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    note.saveNote(titleTextField.text!, detail: detailTextView.text,
        predicate: predicate, fetchRequest: fetchRequest, context: context!)

}
```

This is in the Master VC (just shows a `UITableView` with the note title and date), when creating a new note this is called inside a `UIAlertViewController`:

```
let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
        handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

            //get textfield
            let textField = alert.textFields![0]

            //Set note title
            var noteName: String?
            if textField == "" {
                noteName = "New Note"
            }else {
                noteName = textField.text
            }
            //save the note
            _ = Note(date: NSDate(), title: noteName!, details: "",tag: "defaut", insertIntoManagedContext: self.context)

            do {
                try self.context.save()
            } catch {
                print("Couldn't save context")
            }

    })
```

**Other Info**

This was originally written in Swift 1.2 on Xcode 6.4 and never had an issue. When I upgraded, I ran into lots of problems that are now fixed, so this has never worked on Xcode 7.
From what I know, I have not written anything in any functions that are called when leaving the app.
I tried enabling `Exception Breakpoints` but it didn't pull anything. Nor have I tried to implement multi-threading CoreData.

**EDIT**
When loading the `Detail VC`, then leaving the app and reopening it, the app loads without the error. When moving back to the `Master VC` there is no error, but the `UITableViewController` is empty.

**Edit 2**
As @mundi suggested, there could be a problem with the saving. I am using a fetchedResultsController for this, and when checking what data was pulled I am getting this in the console:

Before leaving the app:

```
Printing description of note:
<Super_Notes.Note: 0x7fe320c22710> (entity: Note; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://48C2DE25-C58B-446F-995F-F97084BCFCCE/Note/p2> ; data: {
    date = "2015-10-15 14:50:32 +0000";
    details = "This is Zetta ";
    noteToData = "<relationship fault: 0x7fe320dbbcb0 'noteToData'>";
    noteToFoler = nil;
    tag = defaut;
    title = Zetta;
})
```

When reopening the app

```
Printing description of note:
<Super_Notes.Note: 0x7fe320c22710> (entity: <null>; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://48C2DE25-C58B-446F-995F-F97084BCFCCE/Note/p2> ; data: <fault>)
```

This is the code I use to pull the note:

```
func configureCell(cell: NoteTableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let note = fetchController.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Note

        //deal with NSDate's crap
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle

        //set date and title Label
        cell.dateLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(note.date)
        cell.titleLabel.text = note.title
    }
```

And this is how I configure the `NSFetchedResultsController` it is called in `viewDidLoad`:

```
func configFetchController() {
        //configure fetch controller
        fetchController.context = context
        let defaultSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
        fetchController.sortDescriptors = [defaultSortDescriptor]
        fetchController.entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Note", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
        fetchController.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        do {
            try fetchController.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            print("An error occured while performing Fetch")
        }
    }
```

If you require anything else, just let me know! :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not saving the date properly when you leave the app. The date formatter would crash with a `nil` date.

I think your `saveNote` function does nothing because the predicate does not retrieve anything. Note that the predicate

```
NSPredicate(format: "self == %@", note.objectID)
```

will always be false. That means that `first` of the result will be nil and no object is actually modified or saved. If you want a predicate for a specific object, it should be

```
NSPredicate(format: "self = %@", note)
```

Your `saveNote` function seems somewhat contrived. Would it not be much simpler to just send the parameters you want to update and handle the saving where you modify it?

```
func updateNote(newTitle: String, newDetail: String) {
    self.title = newTitle
    self.detail = newDetail
    self.date = NSDate()
}
```

I suspect you are trying to modify the object potentially on different threads. This matter is more complicated and has many caveats, but one thing close to your original design would be to pass a context and an `NSManagedObjectID`.

```
func updateNote(newTitle: String, newDetail: String, context: 
                NSManagedObjectContext, objectId: NSManagedObjectID) {
  let note = context.objectWithID(objectId) as! Note
  note.title = newTitle
  note.detail = newDetail
  note.date = NSDate()
  do { try context.save() } catch {}
}
```

If you use this with a child context, you still need to make sure that all contexts are saved before you leave the app, or the changes will not be written to the persistent store.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to respond, quite busy with Canadian thanksgiving and all. I am not sure if it isn't saving correctly, as I went through some debugging and found that the note when configuring the cell has `data: <fault>` in the logs. I have updated my post

Comment: `fault` does not mean the data is not saved, just that the framework has not loaded all data into memory. You could instead inspect the actual sqlite file, e.g. using the command line tool `sqlite3` (built into OS X).

Comment: Right, I just read that fault can be used to show it's not loaded into memory - which is what this error is about which is why I'm confused :(. How would I find the sqlite file ?

Comment: Oh. My. Goodness. I forgot to clear a `NSNotificationCenter` that was tracking `UITextField`s and `UITextView`s changes and causing a save that wasn't working. Wow. Wowowowowow. I feel like an idiot. Thanks for all the help!